# Percentage difference between numbers in two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

My SQL experience is fairly minimal so please go easy on me here. I have a table `tblForEx` and I'm trying to create a query that looks at one particular column `LastSalesRateChangeDate` and also `ForExRate`.

Basically what I want to do is for the query to check that `LastSalesRateChangeDate` and then pull the `ForExRate` that is on the same line (obviously in the `ForExRate` column), then I need to check to see if there is a +/- 5% change since the last time the `LastSalesRateChangeDate` changed. I hope this makes sense, I tried to explain it as clearly as possible.

I believe I would need to create a 'subquery' to look at the `LastSalesRateChangeDate` and pull the `ForEx` rate from that date, but I just don't know how to go about this.

I should add this is being done in Access (SQL)

Sample data, here is what the table looks like:

```
| BaseCur | ForCur | ForExRate | LastSalesRateChangeDate
| USD     | BRL    | 1.718     | 12/9/2008      
| USD     | BRL    | 1.65      | 11/8/2008
```

So I would need a query to look at the `LastSalesRateChangeDate` column, check to see if the date has changed, if so take the `ForExRate` value and then give a percentage difference of that `ForExRate` value since the last record.

So the final result would likely look like

```
"BaseCur" "ForCur" "Percentage Change since Last Sales Rate Change"
USD         BRL            X%
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description.

Comment: Added some sample data to my question.

Comment: 2 questions: so would it be 1.718/1.65 or 1.65/1.78? and if you don't have a previous value what do you want to return? 1? 0? Null?

Comment: It would be 1.65/1.78, Null would likely be the best option if there was nothing to return. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's answer pointed in the right direction:

```
SELECT t2.*, (SELECT top 1 t.ForExRate
FROM tblForEx t
where t.BaseCur=t2.BaseCur AND t.ForCur=t2.ForCur and t.LastSalesRateChangeDate<t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate
order by t.LastSalesRateChangeDate DESC, t.ForExRate DESC
) AS PreviousRate, [ForExRate]/[PreviousRate]-1 AS ChangeRatio
FROM tblForEx AS t2;
```

Access gives errors where the `TOP 1` in the subquery causes "ties". We broke the ties and therefore removed the error by adding an extra item to the `ORDER BY` clause. To get the ratio to display as a percentage, switch to the design view and change the properties of that column accordingly.

Comment: This isn't giving me a percentage at all in the output table, and I get an error box which reads 'At most one record can be returned with this subquery'

Comment: Hmm, I'm not getting that locally. I did have to change the format of the display of the ChangeRatio column to %, though. What version of MS Access are you running. I tested in 2013.

Comment: I'm using 2016 Steve, could that be the issue?

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't follow why that would be a problem. I'll have to do some research. Of course, the subquery is only meant to return 1 record (per row of the outer query).

Comment: I wonder if you have cases of "ties" in the data where you have more than one record with the same ChangeDate for the same BaseCur and ForCur combination?

Comment: To avoid, you might want to add something extra to the Order By in the sub-query, or perhaps even a "distinct" or perhaps both.

Comment: Just had a quick check of the data, there could be duplicates in there, I'd likely want to go by the 'greater' of the two numbers in the cases of duplicates if that would be possible

Comment: I've added an extra item in the `order by` to handle that. If you have mutiple rows with the same rate also, then the issue will remain.

Comment: Thanks Steve, now when I try running your new code I get an input box 'Enter Parameter Value' and its asking for t.ForExDate?

Comment: Also interesting, if I hit Ok I'm getting the same At most one record can be returned by this subquery and the ChangeRatio field is completely blank

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I've just corrected it. `ForExDate` - > `ForExRate`

Comment: That looks like it worked! Now one last question, if I want that decimal to display as a percentage instead of a long decimal number, what would I add?

Comment: Access can handle that via formatting of the column if you switch to "design" view and edit the properties of that column. Or you can multiply by 100 etc.

Comment: Got it! Steve I want to thank you so much for the help, I was trying allsorts to get this to work and your method is working wonders now, I have the percentages showing fine. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent. Glad we got there. Please accept and upvote my answer by way of a thank you and to help other users find working answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the previous value.  In MS Access, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select top (1) t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate
        from tblForEx as t2
        where t2.BaseCur = t.BaseCur and t2.ForCur = t.ForCur
              t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate < t.LastSalesRateChangeDate
        order by t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate desc
       ) as prev_LastSalesRateChangeDate
from t;
```

Now, with this as a subquery, you can get the previous exchange rate using a `join`:

```
select t.*, ( (t.ForExRate / tprev.ForExRate) - 1) as change_ratio
from (select t.*,
             (select top (1) t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate
              from tblForEx as t2
              where t2.BaseCur = t.BaseCur and t2.ForCur = t.ForCur
                    t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate < t.LastSalesRateChangeDate
              order by t2.LastSalesRateChangeDate desc
             ) as prev_LastSalesRateChangeDate
      from t
     ) as t inner join
     tblForEx as tprev
     on tprev.BaseCur = t.BaseCur and tprev.ForCur = t.ForCur
        tprev.LastSalesRateChangeDate = t.prev_LastSalesRateChangeDate;
```

Comment: Gordon this definitely looks like it's going to do what I want, now subqueries are something that are completely new to me, would I essentially need to create the bottom query and link it to the top one?

I'm not sure how to reference a subquery from the bottom 'join' query

Comment: you just need the bottom one.  the top one is embedded in the bottom.

Comment: Also, presume I should replace all 't' with 'tblForEx' correct? I understand the t2 is the temp table

Comment: Ah I don't know how I didn't notice that, the bottom one contains the whole query, now I just need to work out if every 't' needs to be tblForEx, I presume it does? But 't2' are fine the way they are?

Comment: I've tried running that code as is, and also changing the 't' to my table named tblForEx but I'm getting 'syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '',

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you can use LEAD function to get last changed date Rate in a new column by using below query:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, LEAD(ForExRate, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY BaseCur, ForCur ORDER BY LastChangeDate DESC) LastValue
FROM #TT
)
SELECT BaseCur, ForCur, ForExRate, LastChangeDate , CAST( ((ForExRate - ISNULL(LastValue, 0))/LastValue)*100 AS float)
FROM CTE
```

Problem here is:

1. for every last row in group by you will have new calculalted column which we have made using LEAD function.
2. If there is only a single row for a particular BaseCur and ForCur, then also you will have NULL in column.

Resolution:
If you are sure that there will be at least two rows for each BaseCur and ForCur, then you can use WHERE clause to remove NULL values in final result.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, LEAD(ForExRate, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY BaseCur, ForCur ORDER BY LastChangeDate DESC) LastValue
FROM #TT
)
SELECT BaseCur, ForCur, ForExRate, LastChangeDate , CAST( ((ForExRate - ISNULL(LastValue, 0))/LastValue)*100 AS float) Percentage
FROM CTE
    WHERE LastValue IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Access does not support the LEAD or LAG function. It is a bit primitive when it comes to SQL support.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT basetbl.BaseCur, basetbl.ForCur, basetbl.NewDate, basetbl.OldDate, num2.ForExRate/num1.ForExRate*100 AS PercentChange FROM 
(((SELECT t.BaseCur, t.ForCur, MAX(t.LastSalesRateChangeDate) AS NewDate, summary.Last_Date AS OldDate
FROM (tblForEx AS t 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 2 BaseCur, ForCur, MAX(LastSalesRateChangeDate) AS Last_Date FROM tblForEx AS t1 
            WHERE LastSalesRateChangeDate <> 
            (SELECT MAX(LastSalesRateChangeDate) FROM tblForEx t2 WHERE t2.BaseCur = t1.BaseCur AND t2.ForCur = t1.ForCur) 
            GROUP BY BaseCur, ForCur) AS summary 
        ON summary.ForCur = t.ForCur AND summary.BaseCur = t.BaseCur)
GROUP BY t.BaseCur, t.ForCur, summary.Last_Date) basetbl
LEFT JOIN tblForEx num1 ON num1.BaseCur=basetbl.BaseCur AND num1.ForCur = basetbl.ForCur AND num1.LastSalesRateChangeDate = basetbl.OldDate))
LEFT JOIN tblForEx num2 ON num2.BaseCur=basetbl.BaseCur AND num2.ForCur = basetbl.ForCur AND num2.LastSalesRateChangeDate = basetbl.NewDate;
```

This uses a series of subqueries. First, you are selecting the most recent date for the BaseCur and ForCur. Then, you are joining onto that the previous date. I do that by using another subquery to select the top two dates, and exclude the one that is equal to the previously established most recent date. This is the "summary" subquery.

Then, you get the BaseCur, ForCur, NewDate, and OldDate in the "basetbl" subquery. After that, it is two simple joins of the original table back onto those dates to get the rate that was applicable then.

Finally, you are selecting your BaseCur, ForCur, and whatever formula you want to use to calculate the rate change. I used a simple ratio in that one, but it is easy to change. You can remove the dates in the first line if you want, they are there solely as a reference point.

It doesn't look pretty, but complicated Access SQL queries never do.